# IE won't load directly-linked PNGs

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I remember having this issue in the past with previous versions as well but recently it started here again. Whenever I click a link that links directly to a PNG image I get a download dialog; the browser won't display it on its own. Inline PNGs are fine, though.

**ETA:** It apparently only happens from PNG images *linked from RSS feeds.* Maybe it has always been so, I can't really say.

**ETA2:** IE 8 it is, as should be common sense but apparently it needs to be stated explicitly *sigh*.

Any ideas what causes this? It did work in the past.

<sub>*Preemptive warning:* I'm not looking for advice to change my browser; I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem with one piece of software. Just ignore the fact that it may have religious importance.</sub>

Comment: You didn't even say what version of IE...

Comment: Indeed. Did you try it with the latest IE9?

Comment: I think he should use Chrome.

Comment: :D Doesn't make too much sense. Chrome is still under construction. When it will bring normal AdBlock (preemptive functions, not just adblock), etc. Won't list all the issues. Firefox would be a good choice because the market share forces web devs to support it. :)

Comment: I also think Safari or Opera will solve these problems.

Comment: @Lo'oris: Use common sense. Edited, though.

Comment: Ehm. Have you ever seen a market share graph or something? Its not that obvious that you use IE8. At least I saw people asking for help with even IE6 or IE7.

Answer (score -2):

> Preemptive warning: I'm not looking for advice to change my browser; I'm looking for a solu-

Chrome.

> It apparently only happens from PNG images linked from RSS feeds. Maybe it has always been so, I can't really say.

As far as some things to get you started troubleshooting this, you may want to look at [MIME Sniffing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx) in Internet Explorer. It will try and infer the type of resource being requested, rather than look at the MIME type.

There is also a miscellaneous option under "Security Zones" called `Open files based on content, not file extension`, which invokes the above behaviour.

There are some extended controls for it in the registry, down the bottom of [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787872(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Great solution. :D